# AD Managed Service Account as SharePoint Managed Account

Tags: active-directory, service-account, managed-account

I'm slightly confused with regards to managed service accounts in Active Directory & SharePoint.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create a managed service account in AD with "New-ADServiceAccount" & the rest of the steps like installing and adding it to the SP server.
2. Then go to SharePoint Central Admin and Register a new Managed Account.
3. On the "Register Managed Account" it asks for the user name and password of the account. However when you use the AD PowerShell command New-ADServiceAccount, the service account automatically gets assigned a password. So I'm not able to give it to SharePoint, when registering a new managed account.

So, my question is:
1.  When SP asks for a new managed account, is it referring to a managed AD account created with the New-ADServiceAccount? Or is SP referring to a standard non-managed service account/user account?

1. If I don't have the password of the ADServiceAccount, how do I register it in SharePoint as a managed account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been confusing 2 different, but related things. Both Active Directory and SharePoint have managed accounts. But SharePoint just refers to a normal AD account where you tell SP to auto update the password according to AD's password policy. AD means literally creating an account managed by AD without a password.

You don't put an ad-managed-service account into SP - you put a normal account there & let SP manage it.